# How to use multi-threading to parallellize a for loop in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, design-patterns, java-8

I am writing a code which picks the multiple API call details from a file and executes those ones by one and provides the response data in an ArrayList. Below is my current code.

```
ArrayList<APICallDetails> apiCallDetailsArray = new ArrayList<>();
APICallDetails apiCallDetails = new APICallDetails();
for (count= 1; count <= callsCount; count++){
        try{
            apiCallDetails = new APICallDetails();
            apiCallDetails.setName(property.getPropertyReader(callName+"_"+count+"_Name", propsFile));
            apiCallDetails.setHost(marketConfigs.getRawJson().get(property.getPropertyReader(callName+"_"+count+"_Host", propsFile)).toString().replaceAll("\"", ""));
            apiCallDetails.setPath(property.getPropertyReader(callName+"_"+count+"_Path", propsFile));
            apiCallDetails.setMethod(property.getPropertyReader(callName+"_"+count+"_Method", propsFile));
            apiCallDetails.setBody(property.getPropertyReader(callName+"_"+count+"_Body", propsFile));

            apiCallDetails = sendAPIRequest.mwRequestWithoutBody(apiCallDetails, marketConfigs);
            BufferedWriter out = null;
            try {
                out = new BufferedWriter ( new FileWriter ( "C:\\file"+count+".html"));
                    out.write("something");
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    logger.error(new Date()+" - Error in "+getClass()+".apiCallRequester() flow: "+e.toString());
                }

            apiCallDetailsArray.add(apiCallDetails);

        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error(new Date()+" - Error in "+getClass()+".apiCallRequester() flow: "+e.toString());
        }
    }
```

As there are more API calls, this is taking the sum of the response time of all the calls. I want these calls to run parallelly and store the response data in an ArrayList which I can use further. 
I am new to Java so, can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Look into CompletableFuture.

Comment: This for-loop is a bit old-fashioned, too. Look into the Streams API for a more expressive iteration construct. (Bonus, streams are trivial to parallelize). Beware, Java objects aren’t all inherently threadsafe, and `sendAPIRequest` might not take kindly to being invoked in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use parallel streams. The following invocation will invoke in parallel `createAPICallDetails(idx)` and add their return objects into a `List`:

```
    List<APICallDetails> result = IntStream.range(0, callsCount)
            .parallel()
            .mapToObj(idx -> createAPICallDetails(idx))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So, the only thing left for you is to implement the logic of:

```
    APICallDetails createAPICallDetails(int index) { ... }
```

To create a single object of your `APICallDetails` given the `index` argument, so it can be used in the previous lambda.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Macro R.!! 
I have tried implementing this in my code by getting below error in my logs and my web application is throwing 404 HTTP status on all the pages.

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Bharat\IDEs\JavaWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\R6TestKit\WEB-INF\classes\com\capgemini\controller\APICallController.class]; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 153

Comment: The code I shared effectively runs a loop in parallel. I suggest you create a new different question with all the relevant details, since this new problem is out of the scope of the current question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!
Yes, I also agree that it is a complelety different thing. But somehow the above code is the only reason which is causing this error. When I remove this code snippet from my code, everything starts working. And whenever I add it again; it stops the startup of the web app.

Comment: Make sure you implement `APICallDetails createAPICallDetails(int index) { ... }` correctly. For instance the code I gave you already creates the `List` and add all elements, so there's no need for `apiCallDetailsArray.add(apiCallDetails)` or any list manipulation, just create the object and return it.

Comment: Thanks Marco!! It was a great help to me. I have just moved the code from the controller to service Class and it started working.